# show image in ToolstripLabel from app config file

Tags: c#, app-config, desktop-application, toolstripitem

*Case:* I have a **Desktop application** in which I need to show Customized Images as per Logged In Vendor. So, in `App.config`, the image file is added as a key:

```
<add key="Logo" value="companylogo_2.jpg"/>
```

How to consume it in `ToolstripLabel` control?

*Note:* **In App.config file, value does not contain full path of image, just the Name of Image**

*Trials:*
**1.**

```
smallImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Logo"]));
```

**2.**

```
string CurrDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
smallImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(CurrDirectory,ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Logo"])));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for zero Help! Anyways, I figured it out.

**Steps :**
*Read the value from `App.config`*:

```
public string imgLogo = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Logo"].ToString();
```

*Get full path using* : `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` as:

```
`System.Drawing.Image myImage = Image.FromFile(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\" + imgLogo + "");`
```

*Assign value to* `toolStripLabel` *as*:

```
toolStripLabel1.Image = myImage;
```